# How to implement joins for 5 table using prodataset in progress 4GL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have 5 tables which are related with parent child relationship. like table1 -> table2->table3->table4->table5, here arrow shows parent to child relation. how can i fetch records from these related tables using prodataset in progress 4GL?
how can i define queries for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with 1 table joined, just add more tables to cQuery using the ,FIRST  format.

```
    ASSIGN
      cQuery = "FOR EACH table1 NO-LOCK ":U
             + "   WHERE table1.product_obj = ":U + QUOTER(cProduct)
             + "     AND table1.role_obj    = ":U + QUOTER(cRole)
             + "  ,FIRST table2 NO-LOCK ":U
             + "   WHERE table2.criterion_obj = table1.criterion_obj":U.

    hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(BUFFER table1:HANDLE, BUFFER table2:HANDLE).

    hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE(cQuery) NO-ERROR.
    hQuery:QUERY-OPEN() NO-ERROR.
    hQuery:GET-FIRST() NO-ERROR.

    DO  WHILE NOT hQuery:QUERY-OFF-END:
        <put logic here>
        hQuery:GET-NEXT() NO-ERROR.
    END.
```

============

For ProDataSets you will need to define your temp-tables
then create the ProDataSets

example from manual:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOrder LIKE Order
    FIELD OrderTotal AS DECIMAL
    FIELD CustName LIKE Customer.NAME
    FIELD RepName LIKE SalesRep.RepName.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOline LIKE OrderLine.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttItem
    FIELD ItemNum LIKE ITEM.ItemNum
    FIELD ItemName LIKE ITEM.ItemName
    FIELD Price LIKE ITEM.Price
    FIELD Weight LIKE ITEM.Weight
    FIELD OnHand LIKE ITEM.OnHand
    FIELD OnOrder LIKE ITEM.OnOrder.

DEFINE DATASET dsOrder FOR ttOrder, ttOline, ttItem
DATA-RELATION OrderLine FOR ttOrder, ttOline
RELATION-FIELDS (OrderNum, OrderNum)
DATA-RELATION LineItem FOR ttOline, ttItem
RELATION-FIELDS (ItemNum, ItemNum).

DEFINE VARIABLE hDSOrder AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
hDSOrder = DATASET dsOrder:HANDLE.

DEFINE QUERY qOrder FOR Order, Customer, SalesRep.
DEFINE QUERY qItem FOR ITEM.
DEFINE DATA-SOURCE srcOrder FOR QUERY qOrder
Order KEYS (OrderNum), Customer KEYS (CustNum), SalesRep KEYS (SalesRep).
DEFINE DATA-SOURCE srcOline FOR OrderLine.
DEFINE DATA-SOURCE srcItem FOR QUERY qItem ITEM KEYS (ItemNum).

BUFFER ttOrder:ATTACH-DATA-SOURCE(DATA-SOURCE srcOrder:HANDLE,
"Customer.Name,CustName").
BUFFER ttOline:ATTACH-DATA-SOURCE(DATA-SOURCE srcOline:HANDLE).
BUFFER ttItem:ATTACH-DATA-SOURCE(DATA-SOURCE srcItem:HANDLE).

QUERY qOrder:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH Order WHERE Order.OrderNum = 1, " +
    "FIRST Customer OF Order, FIRST SalesRep OF Order"). /* setup query to fill 
     dataset */

hDSOrder:FILL(). /* fill the ProDataSet as a whole */
```

Comment: i tried same type of query and used it. it gives correct results. but now i have to do it using PRODATA SETs. and the query is not working. if i use separate query for each of these 5 tables and define data source of each of these queries and fill data set then it is taking 1 min to fetch record, for same thing a simple query requires 1 sec. because when i prepare query for prodataset, it is having "for each" statement. i tried to use first table_name, or For first table_name but i m getting error as use for each for first buffer. please help me out with this.

Comment: yeah... i tried this also... but here i have to prepare query qItem also. While preparing Query qItem, we have to use for each item. this works and gives output. But when i have 5 tables then for next 4 queries i have to use for each and it affects query performance very badly. i am having nearly 15000 records in each table and that type of query takes 1 hr when i execute dataset fill operation.

Comment: hey i tried above code for sports database. it is giving answer but it takes almost 1 min to execute. my database i having 15000 records in each table. Its gonna take hours to execute. I want to optimize performance

Comment: Post the slow query as a question (include data definition if possible) and someone might take a look at it...

Comment: Horses for courses. Like Jensd said. Post the code and lets look at it, maybe there is just a problem with your query. But sometimes there are different ways of doing something and 1 method will work better/more efficient than another method.